# Optimizing very lengthy code with a lot of if statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding a game in Unity and I would like help optimizing horribly messy code that I don't know how to optimize. I'm thinking that maybe a for loop would help, but I apparently am bad at using for loops. Here is the code in question:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

class listComparer : IComparer<int>
{
    public int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // CompareTo() method
        return x.CompareTo(y);

    }
}

public class battleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Enemies
    public GameObject activeEnemies;

    //Text Box
    public battleTextBox daTextBox;

    //Getting data from beforehand
    public string enemy1ID;
    public string enemy2ID;
    public string enemy3ID;
    public string enemy4ID;
    public string enemy5ID;
    public string enemy6ID;

    public string flavorText;

    //enemy speeds
    public int enemy1speed;
    public int enemy2speed;
    public int enemy3speed;
    public int enemy4speed;
    public int enemy5speed;
    public int enemy6speed;

    public int totalTurnOrder;

    public bool texting;

    //The protagonists
    public characterstats Micheal;
    public characterstats Zage;
    public characterstats Orego;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("RealStart");
    }

    IEnumerator RealStart()
    {
        // Getting all speed values
        enemy1speed = activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().speed;

        if (enemy2ID != "none")
        {
            enemy2speed = activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().speed;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy2speed = -1;
        }

        if (enemy3ID != "none")
        {
            enemy3speed = activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().speed;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy3speed = -1;
        }

        if (enemy4ID != "none")
        {
            enemy4speed = activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().speed;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy4speed = -1;
        }

        if (enemy5ID != "none")
        {
            enemy5speed = activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().speed;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy5speed = -1;
        }

        if (enemy6ID != "none")
        {
            enemy6speed = activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().speed;
        }
        else
        {
            enemy6speed = -1;
        }

        List<int> speeds = new List<int>();

        speeds.Add(enemy1speed);

        if (enemy2speed != -1)
        {
            speeds.Add(enemy2speed);
        }

        if (enemy3speed != -1)
        {
            speeds.Add(enemy3speed);
        }

        if (enemy4speed != -1)
        {
            speeds.Add(enemy4speed);
        }

        if (enemy5speed != -1)
        {
            speeds.Add(enemy5speed);
        }

        if (enemy6speed != -1)
        {
            speeds.Add(enemy6speed);
        }

        speeds.Add(Micheal.speed);
        speeds.Add(Zage.speed);
        speeds.Add(Orego.speed);

        listComparer speedSort = new listComparer();

        speeds.Sort(speedSort);

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 0)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 0)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 0)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 0)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 0)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 0)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 0)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 0)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 1;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 0)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 1;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 1)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 1)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 1)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 1)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 1)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 1)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 1)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 1)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 2;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 1)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 2;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 2)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 2)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 2)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 2)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 2)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 2)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 2)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 2)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 3;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 2)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 3;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 3)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 3)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 3)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 3)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 3)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 3)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 3)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 3)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 4;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 3)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 4;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 4)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 4)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 4)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 4)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 4)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 4)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 4)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 4)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 5;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 4)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 5;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 5)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 5)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 5)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 5)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 5)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 5)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 5)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 5)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 6;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 5)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 6;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 6)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 6)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 6)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 6)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 6)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 6)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 6)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 6)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 7;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 6)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 7;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 7)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 7)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 7)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 7)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 7)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 7)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 7)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 7)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 8;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 7)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 8;
        }


        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy1speed) == 8)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy2speed) == 8)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy3speed) == 8)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy4speed) == 8)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy5speed) == 8)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(enemy6speed) == 8)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Micheal.speed) == 8)
        {
            Micheal.turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Zage.speed) == 8)
        {
            Zage.turnOrder = 9;
        }

        if (speeds.IndexOf(Orego.speed) == 8)
        {
            Orego.turnOrder = 9;
        }

        totalTurnOrder = speeds.Count;

        if (activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder ||
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder ||
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder ||
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder ||
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder ||
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            texting = true;
            StartCoroutine(daTextBox.PrintText(flavorText, 2, 3f, 0.025f));
            yield return new WaitWhile(() => texting);
        }

        if (activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy1ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().myTurn();
        }

        if (activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy2ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().myTurn();
        }

        if (activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy3ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().myTurn();
        }

        if (activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy4ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().myTurn();
        }

        if (activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy5ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().myTurn();
        }


        if (activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            activeEnemies.transform.Find(enemy6ID).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().myTurn();
        }

        if (Micheal.turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            Micheal.myTurn();
        }

        if (Zage.turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            Zage.myTurn();
        }

        if (Orego.turnOrder == totalTurnOrder)
        {
            Orego.myTurn();
        }

        if (Micheal.turnIsMine == true || Zage.turnIsMine == true || Orego.turnIsMine == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(daTextBox.PrintText(flavorText, 2, 3f, 0.025f));
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much to anyone who figures this out.
P.S. This code is for determining the turn order in an RPG battle system

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking to improve working code - ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: What does "I apparently am bad at using for loops" mean?  If you show what you attempted with loops someone can help you understand how to...be good at using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend searching about object oriented architecture and trying to create an Enemy class. Then, you can create a List and iterate through each enemy as such:

```
int highestSpeed = -1;
Enemy fastestEnemy = -1;
foreach(Enemy enemy in Enemies) {
    if(enemy.speed > highestSpeed) {
        highestSpeed = enemy.speed;
        fastestEnemy = enemy;
    }
}
if(fastestEnemy == null)
    //no enemy had a speed higher than -1
```

Alternatively, if you want a simpler approach, put the ids and speeds into an array and do the same thing:

```
public string[] EnemyIDs = new string[6];

EnemyIDs[0] = .....
EnemyIDs[1] = .....
//So on and so forth, remembering that arrays are zero based, so EnemyIDs[0] is the first element of the array, and that EnemyIDs[6] is not going to work, since it will be accessing the 7th object of a size 6 array (Out of bounds exception)

public int[] EnemySpeeds = new int[6];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if(EnemyIDs[i] == "None")
        EnemySpeeds[i] = -1;
    else
        EnemySpeeds[i] = activeEnemies.transform.Find(EnemyIDs[i]).gameObject.GetComponent<enemyStats>().speed;
}

int highestSpeed = -1;
int fastestEnemyID = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if(EnemySpeeds[i] > highestSpeed) {
        highestSpeed = EnemySpeeds[i];
        fastestEnemyID = EnemyIDs[i];
    }
}
```

Have fun!